# Окрыть номер телефона нажатием на кнопку python requests

Tags: python, парсер, post, requests, get

Есть сайт, номер телефона скрыт и требуется нажатие на кнопку. [image: кнопка скрыта, требуется нажатие]

смотрю код, там вот это
[image: код кнопки]

иду в Network, кликаю на кнопку и получаю запросы, которые улетают при клике:
[image: requests]

первый запрос после нажатия кнопки post, но в ответе номер телефона отсутствует, судя по ссылкам там вобще статистика какая-то. Остальные запросы так же не дают намека о номере телефона. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне его (номер телефона) получить не используя selenium.[image: response post]

adId так же присутствует в ссылке на обявление:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссылку на сайт можно? а так поищи в яваскрипте

Comment: https://www.gumtree.pl/a-akcesoria-i-czesci-komputerowe/poznan/adapter-konwerter-hdmi-do-vga-full-hd-1080p/1002503981360910468346809